# Render input before label with Twig or form builder

Tags: php, symfony, materialize

I'm using [materialize](http://materializecss.com) for the front end and I have an issue with the rendering of checkbox,  to make the materialize checkbox works I've to put the label after the input but I build the form with symfony so this puts the label before the input. Here is how I build my form :

```
$builder
->add('libelle')
->add('ordre')
->add('categorie')
    ->add('type', ChoiceType::class, array(
        'choices'  => array(
            'Commande' => 'commande',
            'Produit' => 'produit',
            'Face'      => 'face',
            'Job'       => 'job'
        )
    ))
    ->add('fin', CheckboxType::class, array(
        'label'    => 'Fin action'
    ));
```

And I render the form like this :

```
{{ form_start(edit_form, {'attr': {'class': 'full'}}) }}
  {{ form_widget(edit_form) }}
{{ form_end(edit_form) }}
```

Is there a way with the form builder or twig to render the label after the input ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can output label and field separately in Twig:

```
{{ form_label(field_name) }}
{{ form_widget(field_name) }}
```

Comment: If rendering label and widget seperately doesn't achieve what you are trying to do take a look at the options to customize form rendering: http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html